# Firebase call data

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my first code:

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      horizontal: 20,
      vertical: 0,
    ),
    child: Text(
      " i want get data here",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xFF737599),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

thats my second code :

```
 return Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: Container(
    height: size.height * 0.4,
    child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _statusService.getStatus(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return !snapshot.hasData
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 1,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot movies = snapshot.data.docs[2];
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 20,
                        vertical: 0,
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 20,
                          vertical: 0,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "${movies['description']}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: Color(0xFF737599),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
        }),
  ),
);
```

I want to pull a text from firebase. I managed to do this (on a different dart page), but how can I integrate it into the code I wrote before (there was a part where I printed the text manually without using firebase, how can I integrate it into that part).

In short, I want to integrate the text part in the first code, the part where I get data from the pharaoh in the second code.

I'm sharing both parts of the code, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is not a best practice what you do but you can create class attribute and you can assgin'it in your second code like

````
var yourVar = "";


 Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20,
          vertical: 0,
        ),
        child: (yourVar!="")?Text(
          yourVar,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Color(0xFF737599),
          ),
        ) ?null,
      ),
```

in your second code 

```
 return Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: Container(
    height: size.height * 0.4,
    child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _statusService.getStatus(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          return !snapshot.hasData
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 1,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot movies = snapshot.data.docs[2];
setState(() { yourVar= newValue; });
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 20,
                        vertical: 0,
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 20,
                          vertical: 0,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "${movies['description']}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: Color(0xFF737599),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
        }),
  ),
);
````